# Android: DiskLruCache not saved after application closed

Tags: java, android, caching, bitmap, gallery

I'm new to SO and also new to Android programming! So pardon me if the question is trivial.

Anyway, I'm trying to create a gallery application that will show the thumbnails of all media files (videos and pictures) in a folder. My application is running good except for the long waiting time to process the image to get its sampled bitmap.

I've settled this using memory cache (LruCache) but it only solves the problem when user stays in the app and navigate around. Everytime the user closes the app and re-opens it, it'll re-generate the cache again.

After doing some readings online, I decided to add disk cache on top of memory cache, hoping that it'll solve the problem. But even after I implemented it, the problem still persists. Not sure if I'm doing it wrong.

Below is my code to initialize the memory cache and disk cache.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        displayManager.cancelAsyncTask();
        path = savedInstanceState.getString(ARG_POSITION);
    }else{
        // Get memory class of this device, exceeding this amount will throw an
        // OutOfMemory exception.
        final int memClass = ((ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();

        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        final int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 8;

        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                // The cache size will be measured in bytes rather than number of items.
                return bitmap.getByteCount();   
            }
        };
        Log.d("DEBUG_CACHE","context is "+this);
        File cacheDir = getDiskCacheDir(this, DISK_CACHE_SUBDIR);
        Log.d("DEBUG_CACHE", "cache dir is "+cacheDir.getAbsolutePath());
        new InitDiskCacheTask().execute(cacheDir);
    }

    ArrayList<File> folderList = dataManager.getFolderListWithPhotoOrVideo(path);
    ArrayList<File> thumbList = dataManager.getAllPhotosAndVideos(path);

    displayManager.setCurrentPath(path);
    displayManager.setParent(this);
    displayManager.setMemCache(mMemoryCache);
    displayManager.setFolderList(folderList);
    displayManager.setThumbnails(thumbList);
}
```

Below is how I get the thumbnails from cache if exists and how I add the bitmap to the cache.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    int noOfThumbnails = thumbnails.size();
    for(int j=0;j<noOfThumbnails;j++){
        String filePath = thumbnails.get(j).getName();
        if(isPhoto(filePath)){
            //if file is an image file
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(thumbnails.get(j).getAbsolutePath()));
            Bitmap thumb = getBitmapFromMemCache(filePath);
            if(thumb==null){
                thumb = getBitmapFromDiskCache(filePath);
                if(thumb==null){
                    thumb = getPreview(uri);
                    addBitmapToCache(filePath,thumb);
                }
            }
            bitmaps.add(thumb);
        }else{
            Bitmap thumb = getBitmapFromMemCache(filePath);
            if(thumb==null){
                thumb = getBitmapFromDiskCache(filePath);
                if(thumb==null){
                    thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(thumbnails.get(j).getAbsolutePath(),MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                    addBitmapToCache(filePath,thumb);
                }
            }
            bitmaps.add(thumb);
        }
        double progress = ((double)(j+1)/(double)noOfThumbnails)*100;
        publishProgress(new Double(progress).intValue());
        if(isCancelled()){
            Log.d("DEBUG", "doInBackGround. Task cancelled");
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}  

public void addBitmapToCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);  
    }

    // Also add to disk cache
    synchronized (parent.mDiskCacheLock) {
        try {
            if (parent.mDiskLruCache != null && parent.mDiskLruCache.get(key) == null) {
                parent.mDiskLruCache.put(key, bitmap);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return (Bitmap) mMemoryCache.get(key);  
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromDiskCache( String key ) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    Snapshot snapshot = null;
    try {
        snapshot = parent.mDiskLruCache.get( key );
        if ( snapshot == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        final InputStream in = snapshot.getInputStream( 0 );
        if ( in != null ) {
            final BufferedInputStream buffIn = 
            new BufferedInputStream( in, Utils.IO_BUFFER_SIZE );
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( buffIn );              
        }   
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if ( snapshot != null ) {
            snapshot.close();
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

For the DiskLruCache.java, I used the google source file (can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/DiskLruCache.java?r=fcd13b09ef50f290dc0681ebec74fbdfcac969a5)).

Comment: https://github.com/lalit3686/ImageCacheDemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! I got it finally. (My own stupid mistake.... grrr)

Before this I modified the DiskLruCache.java so it validates any key! By default it should only validates any string with regex [a-z0-9_-] that is, there shouldn't any uppercase letter, whitespace, or even newline. I thought this isn't a big deal so I turned it off and accept all strings.

But WRONG! I modified it back to the default and then I modified my key everytime I add or get the cache, and PERFECT!

Thanks! :)